# Delphi Search path vs Library Path vs Browsing Path

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, I can include a folder's source code by adding it to the project Search Path, or adding it to the Library Path.  The Search Path applies only to the current project, while the Library Path applies to any project opened with the IDE.

Other than that, is there any functional difference between the Search and Library paths?

My reason for asking: I have a folder X with source used by project A.  When I include that folder under Project A's search path, it says it cannot find a specific file in that folder.  When I include it under the Library path, then project A compiles fine.

Until now, I was always under the impression that the only difference was that one was project-specific, and the other was global.

While we're on the topic (and at the risk of making a fool of myself): What is the functional difference between "library path" and "browsing path"?

Comment: Debugger will also find files in Library Path.

Comment: you say "When I include that folder under Project A's search path, it says it cannot find a specific file in that folder." That is really the issue pointed here: It should find it. Have you checked that the Search path set with your folder meets your current Target Platform and Build Configuration?

Comment: You missed in your question the "Debug Source path" under "Embarcadero debuggers" in Delphi "Options" :)

Comment: @ServerOverflow, you may be right.  I'm not sure that option existed at the time I wrote the question back in 2009.  At that time, we were trying to migrate a Delphi 5 (!) project to Delphi 2005, which at the time was fairly current.  It was a CodeGear (not Embarcadero) product at that time.  Sadly I don't have a copy installed any more to look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excerpt from my [Delphi book](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Gabriel-Moraru/dp/B0BZFRZQSM):

**The “Library path” field**

This is the path where the compiler looks for files that it needs when it compiles our project.

There are three main categories of paths that we will find here:

1. On the first lines we can see listed Delphi’s own precompiled DCUs. We will talk about precompiled DCUs soon.

[image]

These paths are added here by Delphi’s installer. Don’t touch them, or you will fuckup the whole Delphi and you will have to reinstall - unless you have a backup of the appropriate registry key, which is: KEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0\Library\

2. Next, if you installed 3rd party packages/libraries using their automatic installers, you will see their paths here. Usually, only the folder containing the DCU files (not the Pas files) will be listed here. Here are some examples:

[image]

These paths are automatically added by the above-mentioned installers.
If you want to use 3rd party libraries (such as LightSaber) that don’t have an automatic installer, you will have to enter their path manually, as described below (point 3).

3. Finally, if we built our own library, we would want to manually put the path to this library here.

---

**The “Browsing path” field**

If we Ctrl+Click in the IDE on a routine (like Application.ProcessMessages), the IDE will take us to the source code of ProcessMessages which is in:

> c:\Delphi\source\vcl\Vcl.Forms.pas

How can the IDE know where to look for Vcl.Forms.pas when the “c:\Delphi\source\vcl” folder is not in Library Path?
This is done by Browsing Path. If we look into the “Browsing Path” we see that the VCL folder is already there:

[image: Browsing Path]

When the IDE cannot find an identifier (function, variable, etc) in project’s “Search path” it starts to search in “Library path”. If the identifier is also not there, the IDE looks into the Browsing Folder.

It is critical to understand that the folders listed in the “Browsing Path” are accessible to the IDE (and also to the debugger, so we can step into the source code of our libraries while debugging) but not to the compiler.

[image]

So, in “Browsing Path” we add the folders that hold units that we want to be able to see/browse with Ctrl+Click in the IDE, but we don’t want to be found by the compiler.

I think Embarcadero team screwed up a bit here. They should have used “Compiler paths” instead of “Library paths” and “IDE paths” instead of “Browsing paths”.

---

**The “Debug DCU path” field**

The documentation says, “Specifies the path for the Delphi-compiled units used for debugging”. What it means is that it contains the folder where the Delphi’s debug DCUs are located (see the “Precompiled DCUs” section). We should not touch this.

Usually, we will only have a single folder listed here:

[image]

---

**The “Debug source path” field**

“Debug source path” is a less obvious place where we can enter paths. Here we enter paths to the Pas files that we have them precompiled to speed up the general compilation speed of your project. Note that this is located under the “Embarcadero debuggers” page and not under the “Library” page:

---

**The “Use debug DCUs” field**

Delphi’s units are coming precompiled in two “flavors”: the debug and the release flavor.
So, one might be inclined to think that when we compile our application in Debug mode, the compiler will implicitly use the debug DCUs for RTL/VCL framework. It doesn’t. The compiler will use the debug DCUs for our code, but not the debug DCUs for the RTL/VCL library.

And we can test that easily: we simply build our application in Debug mode and put a breakpoint somewhere in its source code. We will speak about breakpoints and debugging soon. We will see that we can step into our routines when we press the F7 key. But if we try to step into a Delphi routine (let’s say Application.ProcessMessages), we simply can’t. The debugger won’t go in that routine because Delphi compiled the “release” version of Vcl.Forms.pas (the unit where ProcessMessages resides) even if our app was compiled in “Debug” mode.

To force the compiler to link the “debug” version of its VCL/RTL library, we need to activate the “Use Debug DCUs” check box in “Project options”. Careful here! I said, “Project options”, not Delphi’s “Global options”:

[image: Project options delphi]

**When to activate the “Use debug DCUs”?**

If “Use Debug DCUs” option is not activated, and we debug our application, we can only single step through our own code. This is what we want in the most cases, because it is our code that is buggy, not Delphi’s code. It will be quite annoying to keep stepping into Delphi’s code.

We activate “Use Debug DCUs”:
•   If we want to see how Delphi is working internally – for example, when we want put a break point inside ProcessMessages to see when it is executed.
•   If we think we have found a bug in the RTL/VCL

Note: After we activate this option, we need to re**build** our project! For some changes it is enough to compile, but for others it is not enough. I haven't spent the time to make a list about which ones need to compile and which ones need to build. So, as any lazy person, I always Build, after changing project's options.

[image]

Answer (score 34):

As far as I know, browsing path is where the debugger should look for files when breaking/stepping into source files thats not in the library path.

Lets say that you have a thirdparty component that you use. You point the library path to the directory where the pre-compiled dcu-files of that component are. Your project will use these dcu-files when you compile. This is good, because it wont be recompiled every time you do a build.

But by including the compiled dcu files, you loose the possibility to debug the thirparty component. If you include the path to where the source files are in the browse path, the debugger will find the source, and allow you to step in to it.

The default settings for the vcl show this. In library path they have put $(BSD)\Lib, and in the browsing path they have put $(BDS)\SOURCE\WIN32...

Update:  There are two different kind of search paths: Compiler search path and debugger search path. The first is there the compiler looks for files during compiling, and the second is where the debugger looks for source files during debugging.

The compiler will only find files in the Library path or the projects search path. 
The debugger will find identifiers in the compilers search path plus the browsing path, the debug source path for the project, and the global debug search path.

There should not be any difference in specifying things globally or pr project.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, and that makes sense.  But that means that as a practical matter, all 3 are the same... it is just a matter of organization.  That does not match my experience with this problem.

Comment: No, its not the same. If you include your path in just browse path, it want compile.