# Delphi component install issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, graphics32

After installing a SVN version of graphics32, I cannot see the components in the ToolPallette. (Windows 8.1, Delphi XE)

I mean, I see the group Graphics32, but it's empty.
When I navigate to see Installed Packages, I see the package there, it's checked... and when I click on it, and then click on the "Components" button I can SEE the components, but again, on the component pallette they are not visible.
So I am having problems adding those components to my form.

I just upgraded from version 1.9.1 to version 2.0 (beta) from the SVN trunk because I need functionalities from the latest version, but I have problems installing it correctly.

Please help

Thank you

**EDIT**
After compiling and installing the library, I copied the dcu`s and the pas files to Delphi's folder in program files (Release and Debug), because that is what I do with all my components so I don't depend on later folder changes.

Comment: Sometimes you may need to be open to an actual form designer to see them.

Comment: I started a new project and navigated to the Graphics32 tab, but it's still empty. I restarted the IDe, still empty. I do not know what to do next

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the fact that the folder of my new app... had a space inside ?!?!?! I just made a new project, saved it into a new folder that had no spaces in the name and now I see my components where they should be. This is annoying

Comment: If anyone has a solution for this `bug` please post it so I can accept it. Otherwise I will post my `solution` as an answer. But I would preffere a generic solution that would help other people later on...

Comment: I wouldn't think that would be a problem. I use folders with spaces all the time, in fact the root directory for all my projects has a space in it. Also, when you create a new project, without even saving it... the default app resides inside a folder hierarchy that's guaranteed to have spaces in it.

Comment: Now that you mention it... the components seem to appear all the time, except for that particular first new project... this is annoying. I re-installed the library a few times since then.. trying to make it work, so I have no idea what I did to make it work ;(

Comment: So even now... after the components are shown for every new project I start..., still, the project that I started then does not show the components when I open it. Is this annoying or what?

Comment: You really should not copy files into thee program files folder. I can't imagine why you would do that.

Comment: My first instinct, by the way, was that it was a confusion between VCL and FMX, but then I saw Delphi XE, which did not have Firemonkey. Could it be that you're actually using a newer version of Delphi (with a specific XE number)? Because if I remember right, G32 is VCL only.

Comment: If the components show for all ne projects but not for an existing one it is posible that that specific project has differently configured library paths so component units can't be properly found. I suggest you check the path settings to see if there is any difference between projects.

Comment: So my delphi version is simply XE (no number), so no Firemonkey problem

Comment: Library paths are identical. I created the projects identically, practically I just created a new project, saved it in a location and that is all. After noticing the issue with the original project, (the components were not showing) I retried multiple times to re-install the library. After each try, I started a new project to see if the components were there. I do not remember exactly what I did the last time, when I successfully saw the components in the pallette. After that happened, I tried to re-open my initial (saved) project and I saw that the components were still missing.

Comment: David Heffernan - by copying the files to my RAD Studio folder I try to avoid issues with recompiled DCU's that want to be written there and Windows wont allow it unless I am admin. And also, my components and libraries are located on a different drive, in a folder somewhere. That folder may be subject to relocation someday... and when I do that, all my projects will stop working because my paths will be all over the place... These are the reasons

Comment: No idea why I have a down vote on this question... Is it too boring?

Answer (score 1):

Graphics32 does not come with .dproj files, so you might have to do some adaptations regarding component installation / setup yourself. The reason why these file types are not included can be found [here](http://www.delphitools.info/2011/11/10/dont-publish-your-dproj-groupproj/).

If you open the .dpk files in the IDE (for recent Delphi versions there are runtime and designtime packages) you *can* of course build and install the packages right away. The **designtime package** need to be **install**ed otherwise they won't be shown in the IDE. It should show something like "Package [..]\GR32_DSGN_RSXE1.dpk has been installed". If you have not removed previously installed GR32 packages before you should also get a text for all the new components now installed.

To actually use the components in a project you need to have either the source files or the dcu files be found from Delphi. As mentioned in the comments before this can either be the library or the search paths depending on what you want. For a better explanation see [this question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812042/delphi-search-path-vs-library-path-vs-browsing-path).

In short and as mentioned by [Stefan Glienke in a Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+MichaelRiley-Gunny/posts/1ECD9g2sQVf) you shoud not put source files in your library path as it will cause the files to recompile each time you compile your project.

Instead, you should take some time configuring the packages options in advance (before building / installation) to put the DCU / DCP directly into a place where it can be used. For example you can put something like

> ....\Lib\XE2\$(PLATFORM)\$(CONFIG)

into both packages 'Output path for units' AND 'DCP output path'.

Now after build/installation, just add the path specified there into the library path. In addition you can put the source path into the search path, so that a [CTRL] + Click will find the code as well.

The advantage of this is that the library will be used with the package options, which might differ from your project's options.

As said, other ways are possible here including installing the components directly into a global library path.

This might not explain why the components are not visible in your project, but maybe you should just remove the existing packages (*delete* them from the list, not only uncheck), restart the IDE and reinstall the packages as mentioned above.