# Delphi IDE package load error on %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: delphi, bpl

Using RAD Studio 10.2.3, I have suddenly started getting and error when loading 5 of the FireDAC-related packages at IDE startup, and when loading a project:

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I know that this error means that some package that these failing packages depend on is having the 64-bit version being found before the 32-bit version, and that usually this means that the `PATH` environment variable has gotten screwed up so that the 64-bit path is before the 32-bit path.

I've made sure that the `PATH` is set up correctly. I then wrote a program to recursively walk the list of dependencies in a package and each of those sub-dependencies to find and validate those all necessary packages for 32-bit-ness and path, and have confirmed that for each failing package, all dependencies exist on the right paths and are 32-bit.  But I still get the errors.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a better way to sniff out this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `LoadLibrary()` fails in the same way that `LoadPackage()` does, which was hiding the error from me in my search program.  The solution to that problem is to read the imports list directly from the file rather than using `LoadLibrary()` and `GetPackageInfo()`.  Doing this required me to get a lot more familiar with the PE file structure than I was before.  Here's code to get the imports list from a BPL directly rather than through `LoadLibrary()`:

```
uses
  WinApi.Windows,
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils;

const
  MinModuleSize = SizeOf(TImageDOSHeader) + 
                  SizeOf(UInt32) + 
                  SizeOf(TImageFileHeader);

function GetPEImportsList(const FN: String; SL: TStringList): Boolean;
var
  F:      TFileStream;
  I:      UInt32;
  W:      Word;
  Is32:   Boolean;
  RVAOfs: Cardinal;
  S:      AnsiString;
  CA:     Array[0..7] of AnsiChar;   //used to get the section name
  NA:     Array[0..127] of AnsiChar; //arbitrarily long BPL name buffer
  Buff:   TBytes;
  //all of these structure types are declared in WinApi.Windows
  DHdr:   TImageDOSHeader;
  COFF:   TImageFileHeader;
  Op32:   TImageOptionalHeader32;
  Op64:   TImageOptionalHeader64;
  ISec:   TImageSectionHeader;
  IDes:   TImageImportDescriptor;
begin
  //assume failure
  Result := False;
  Assert(Assigned(SL), 'StringList not assigned');
  SL.Clear;
  //if the file doesn't even exist, bail
  if not FileExists(FN) then
    Exit;
  //open the file
  F := TFileStream.Create(FN, fmOpenRead or fmShareCompat);
  try
    //make sure we have a big enough file
    if F.Size < MinModuleSize then
      Exit;
    //start at the beginning
    F.Seek(0, 0);
    //read DOS header
    F.Read(DHdr, SizeOf(DHdr));
    //is it valid?
    if DHdr.e_magic <> IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE then
      Exit;

    //seek to offset of PE signature
    F.Seek(DHdr._lfanew, 0);
    //read PE signature DWORD
    F.Read(I, SizeOf(I));
    //is it valid?
    if I <> IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE then
      Exit;

    //read the COFF image file header and get bitness
    F.Read(COFF, SizeOf(COFF));
    Is32 := COFF.Machine = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386;

    //does an optional header exist?  If not, it's not a valid file
    if COFF.SizeOfOptionalHeader = 0 then
      Exit;

    //read the "optional" (it's not) header as appropriate for
    //32- or 64-bit modules, and verify the magic number.  We
    //don't do anything with this header here beyond the verify,
    //we're mostly just reading it to get past it.
    if Is32 then begin
      F.Read(Op32, SizeOf(Op32));
      if Op32.Magic <> $10B then  //whoops, not really a 32-bit image
        Exit;
    end
    else begin
      F.Read(Op64, SizeOf(Op64));
      if Op64.Magic <> $20B then  //whoops, not really a 64-bit image
        Exit;
    end;

    //Following the optional header is a set of section headers.  The
    //names of the required BPLs are linked via records in the Imports
    //(.idata) section.  So we start by finding the imports section by
    //walking the section headers.  On most BPLs this will be in header
    //#5, but we do the walk for safety in case it changes in the future.
    W := 0;
    repeat
      Inc(W);
      F.Read(ISec, SizeOf(ISec));
      Move(ISec.Name[0], CA[0], 8);  //done for type safety
    until (StrPas(CA) = '.idata') or (W >= 8);
    if StrPas(CA) <> '.idata' then
      Exit;

    //Many addresses in PE structs are RVAs (Relative Virtual Addresses,
    //the address once loaded into memory) rather than Raw addresses
    //(physical offset in the file.)  The RVA will always be greater than
    //the Raw address, so to get the Raw address for an RVA address, we
    //must subtract the difference between the ISec.VirtualAddress and
    //ISec.PointerToRawData values from any RVA address in the structs.
    RVAOfs := ISec.VirtualAddress - ISec.PointerToRawData;

    //Find and read all the data in the imports table into a buffer.  We
    //do this because we must seek around in the file to get the actual
    //text-string name of each import.
    SetLength(Buff, ISec.SizeOfRawData);
    FillChar(Buff[0], ISec.SizeOfRawData, 0);
    F.Seek(ISec.PointerToRawData, 0);
    F.Read(Buff, ISec.SizeOfRawData);

    //now walk thru the buffer, getting each import descriptor and
    //using its Name pointer to find the text name of the import in
    //the file
    W := 0;
    while W < ISec.SizeOfRawData do begin
      //load the Image Import Descriptor struct from the buffer
      Move(Buff[w], IDes, SizeOf(IDes));
      //IIDes.Name is an RVA.  If it's zero, we're done
      if IDes.Name = 0 then
        Break;
      //seek in the file to the correct spot and read the name
      F.Seek(IDes.Name - RVAOfs, 0);
      FillChar(NA[0], SizeOf(NA), 0);
      F.Read(NA[0], SizeOf(NA));
      //if it's the name of a BPL, add it to our stringlist
      S := StrPas(NA);
      if (S <> '') and (Lowercase(ExtractFileExt(S)) = '.bpl') then
        SL.Add(S);
      //move to the next record
      Inc(W, SizeOf(IDes));
    end;

    //we're done, return success
    Result := True;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Did you find the cause of the error with this? What was it?

Comment: Yes.  I had inadvertently moved the 32-bit version of `bindengine250.bpl` out of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin` to a directory not on the path, so the 64-bit version was being found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how all the code provided in the other post is relevant.  The answer is simpler than that:

This happens when your IDE requires the 32bit version of your BPL, but the 64 bit version is found before the 32 bit version.

**Solution 1:**
Delete all BPLs and recompile them. This time, make sure you compile the 32 bit version.

**Solution 2:**
Check your paths. Make sure that the 32/64 bit BPLs are clearly separated.
An older answer of mine explains how to use the "Search Paths" and "Library Paths": [Delphi Search path vs Library Path vs Browsing Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812042/delphi-search-path-vs-library-path-vs-browsing-path/74998315#74998315)

---

Note: Yes, it would have been cool if the IDE would have clearly indicated who is %1 (the name of the faulty BPL)
:(